# Rust struct field as arc vs. struct as arc

Tags: multithreading, performance, rust, automatic-ref-counting

I have a question regarding the Arc in Rust. I want to do something with multi-threading and stumbled on Arcs to give multiple threads access to the same data. At the moment, I use a struct with the fields being Arcs, and the struct is just *normal*. I use the struct as some kind of configuration and give the function that needs it a clone to the needed field. My question is, would it be better practice to make the struct variable an arc and the fields *normal* than give it to the function and retrieve the needed fields?
I'm very interested in the memory usage and speed differences; are there any, or is it just convenience to use one or the other?

Code I think of:

```rust
struct Config{
   name: String,
   id:   u32,
   ...
}

let myconf = Arc::new(Config::default());

do_stuff(myconf.clone()).await;
...
```

current code:

```rust
struct Config{
   name: Arc<String>,
   id:   Arc<u32>,
   ...
}

let myconf = Config::default();
do_stuff(myconf.name.clone(), myconf.id.clone()).await;
...
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If all fields are `Arc`, it is usually better to hold the entire struct behind an `Arc` instead of just many `Arc`s for each field.

This way, cloning and drops are cheaper (just one reference count bump instead of many), moving the struct around is cheaper (just one pointer instead of many), struct creation is faster (one allocation instead of many), less memory is used (because each `Arc` requires two additional words for the reference count), and cache locality is better (since the data is in contiguous allocation instead of scattered in many), and there is also less pointer chasing.

If you want to hide the fact that an `Arc` is used from the interface, you can have two structs, `Config` and `ConfigInner`, and let `Config` be just a wrapper around `Arc<ConfigInner>`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I really feel stupid now because it sounds so logical.

Comment: @Cron3x it's not stupid! There are also definitely good use cases for having every field an individual Arc, just probably a bit less common.

Comment: Just as an example, one situation where it might make more sense to have each field be a separate `Arc` is where you have different threads needing to access different parts of the struct. In this case it's probably better to have separate structs in the first place, but maybe they need to be together for some other valid reason. Having separate `Arc`s means the threads can modify their fields without blocking access to other fields in other threads. But, again, this probably indicates a redesign might be in order.

Comment: @davidA Even in this case, unless the threads always change their refcount it is better to use a single `Arc`. If the data needs to be mutable you can place each in a different cache line.